# CSS border not auto setting itself next to the text

Tags: html, css, border

So I decided to create a website to learn and expand on my programming knowledge for fun. I wanted to create some basic CSS styles I can use on different pages and wanted to have a title bar or rather box around the title of the page. I don't want this box to extend all the way to the end of the web page but that is all that is happening with the code I have now. As far as I knew using "width: auto" would solve the problem but it isn't else I wouldn't be here now.

**Here is the CSS I am using right now**

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(67, 63, 63);
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.titlebar {
    width: auto;
    color: rgb(67,63,63);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(248, 222, 126);
    border-color: rgb(248, 222, 126);
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 13px;
    
    
  }
```

**The HTML I'm applying the div to (just this one line of text)**

```
<body>
    <div class="titlebar">
        <h1>Welcome To My Website Project</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Below is an image of the problem as well. I don't need the yellow area to go all the way to the right only to the end of the text.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UjXy.png)

I've tried setting the border width in multiple ways with auto and specific values. The values work but I'd like to use auto if I can

Comment: Set `display: inline-block;` on `.titlebar`; no need to set `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content):

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(67, 63, 63);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.titlebar {
  /*  */
  width: fit-content;
  color: rgb(67, 63, 63);
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(248, 222, 126);
  border-color: rgb(248, 222, 126);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="titlebar">
    <h1>Welcome To My Website Project</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```